# How to understand dates in ARIMA model output in R

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I am trying to fit ARIMA model into my stock's Price Closing from 02 Jan 2013 to 31 December 2016. I am trying to find a quick way to it because there is a lot many companies I have to apply on and then I landed to `auto.arima` function. Now my predictive output is I can't understand the dates.

Here is my program:

```
stockdata <- read_csv("~/Desktop/news.csv")
head(stockdata)
attach(stockdata)
plot(Close)
is.ts(stockdata)
xi = ts(stockdata$Close, frequency = 365, start = c(2013, 01, 02))
plot.ts(xi)
is.ts(xi)
xi
adf.test(Close, alternative = "stationary")
pi = auto.arima(xi)
summary(pi)
q = forecast(pi, 10)
plot(q)
plot(forecast(q))
q
```

And here is my final output when I plot my forecast:

[image]

Anyone can please help me fix this if the modelling is wrong or can tell me about those dates would be really helpful.

P.S. I am not in data science and totally Noob.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about. Here, R converted dates (probably originally represented as string) to float. What is relevant is the distance between points (in time). Notice that depending on the convention for that specific market there may be around 250 trading days in a trading year, while you set frequency to 365

Comment: Multiply the fraction by the number of days in a year to understand what day of 2016 it corresponds to. E.g. $0.4356\times365\approx159$, i.e. day 159 of 2016.

Comment: arima modelling ( particularly using auto.arima) is very dangerous when you have missing observations ( like saturday and sunday as @edouard pointed out) AND/OR an inconsistent # of trading days per year AND/OR many anomalies/otltliers/level shifts that may be present reflecting exogenous activity AND/OR possible non-constant error variance  AND/OR possible day-of-the-week effects AND/OR possible holiday effects AND/OR possible monthly effects .

Comment: I should add that my comments are true about any ARIMA software not just auto.arima that tacitly ignores the possible violations that I pointed out.

Comment: Thank you everyone you all were quick and helpful :)
And I didnt knew that auto.arima wont consider those exogenous factors. Just out of curiosity and time efficiency is there any other way to get the arima (p,d,q) and plot rather manually testing for each combination?

Comment: I don't know a better algorithm than `auto.arima` that would be freely available. You would probably have to go for commercial software.